# Angular 7 Http Service GET with body

Tags: angular

I need to call a GET service with information in the body. Where should I pass this information?

```
this.http.get<any[]>(this.urlApi, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear as to what you're asking. If you want to send an object as a request body then just post the object in your service.

```
 const your_object: any = 
    { 
       stuff : 'info', 
       morestuff : 'more info' 
    }

 getStuff(your_object: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://your-url-here.com/', {...your_object})
 }
```

and then parse and do whatever you want with the return (just like GET)

Comment: The above solution should work for what you're looking for. You would pass the information as your_object parameter in proper format

Comment: I tried **this.http.get<any[]>(this.urlApi, {"date": "2018-12-25"})** but didn't work. Argument of type '{ "date": string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"data_casamento"' does not exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; ...